# React Component doesn't fire event

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I've got this small chat app made with react + socket io, it's a basic chat where I put messages in a `<ul>`. Console looks clean, no issues, the component renders, but the socket emit doesn't seem to work. You can test it here http://916ae18b.ngrok.io/

///App.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const webpack = require('webpack');
const webpackMiddleware = require('webpack-dev-middleware');
const config = require('./webpack.config.js');
const compiler = webpack(config);
const server = require('http').Server(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(server);

app.use(webpackMiddleware(compiler, {publicPath:config.output.publicPath}))
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/src'))

io.on('connection', socket => {
    socket.on('message', data => socket.emit('message', data))
})

server.listen(3000, () => console.log('server is up!'))
```

///App.js

```
import React from 'react'
import io from 'socket.io-client'

class App extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {messages: [], value: ''}
        this.handle = this.handle.bind(this)
        this.submit = this.submit.bind(this)
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.socket = io('/')
        this.socket.on('message', data => {
                this.setState({messages:[...this.state.messages, data], value: ''})
                console.log(data);
            })  
    }

    handle(e) {
        this.setState({value: e.target.value})
    }

    submit() {
        if(this.state.value.length!==0) 
            {
                this.socket.emit('message', this.state.value)       
            } 
        console.log(this.state.messages);
    }



    render() {
        let messages = this.state.messages.map((e, i) => <li key={i}>{e}</li>)
            return (<div>
                        <input id='input' onChange = {this.handle} value = {this.state.value}/>
                            <button onClick={this.submit}>Submit!</button>
                                <ul>
                                    {messages}
                                </ul>
                        </div>);
        }
    }

export default App
```

Comment: do you see any error in console

Comment: No...that's why I'm confused

Comment: Just a guess, maybe try binding `this.socket`. So in your constructor, do: `this.socket = this.socket.bind(this)`

Comment: did console.log(data) print anything for you

Comment: you have to bind `this.socket = this.socket.bind()`

Comment: bundle.js:106 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined .. I don't think that's the solution, Maybe I didnt implement sockets the right way or the logic is a little bit messy..